# How can I script `gpg --edit-key` operations?

Tags: bash, gnupg

I acquired a YubiKey and intend to use `pass` with it, so I'm trying to script my key generation and move to card for rotation. To my dismay, gpg doesn't support batch mode in a lot of operations, `--edit-key` and `--edit-card` being part of that list, nor can it do operations based on command-line arguments. I find this appalling in a CLI tool, to say the least!

Obviously I tried redirecting stdin, but while running `gpg --batch --gen-key` in a script complains about ioctl issues for pinentry and requires setting GPG_TTY, here it somehow knows how to use the tty without any help. Convenient...

So how can I script operations of these subcommands, preferably with pin-entry dialogs when required so I don't have to run it myself in the script?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out there's are the `--command-fd` and `--status-fd` options. They can be used like so:

`GPG_TTY=$(tty) gpg --command-fd=0 --status-fd=1 --expert --edit-key $KEY`

In case you want to input passwords through the stdin instead of using pinentry, pass also the `--pinentry-mode loopback` argument.

Comment: `--pinentry-mode loopback` is very useful for MacOS to enter empty passphrase 

Comment: On top of this, I'd love to be able to disable all the stdout/status. even with `--status-file=/dev/null` I get all the key-value information of the keys. I don't want that.

Comment: @CasperBang That's probably because `--status-fd` accepts integers, it expects a file descriptor, not name. Try `--status-fd 3 3>/dev/null` instead, maybe it'll work.

Comment: Thank you a million times

Comment: @Olivetree it did not seem to work (after finally having time to edit my ansible script). I was hoping that not output was displayed, however somehow (even though I assumed ansible would catch std out anyway) it still displays all the information and the options when scripting my way through a menu

Comment: @Casper Bang I also want to suppress gpg output. On my machine gpg opens `/dev/tty` to print some of the messages. I am able to use `--no-tty` to disable this behavior. Full command: `echo ... | gpg --command-fd 0 --quiet --no-tty --edit-key "$KEY" > /dev/null 2> /dev/null`